# How do I view localhost site with Lando and Docker for windows?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I was able to successfully install Lando and Docker for windows. I am able to init the directory with `lando init pantheon` and then did a `lando start` command. And I imported the database from pantheon. How do I view the site on localhost?

Comment: I don't know lando, but if you have a container you can do a docker inspect [container_name] to view the IP. And you have to expose port 80 of your container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output from your lando start command, you should see an EDGE URL like

http://YOURSITENAME.lndo.site

Answer (score 0):

This probably can be resolved by `ipconfig /all` on windows.

According to the [Lando Docs](https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/access-by-other-devices.html#testing-only-locally), apps can locally be accessed as:

> Windows :
>
> Open a command prompt and enter the command ipconfig /all and look for
>   the "IPv4 Address" for the network adapter you use to connect to the
>   Internet. Make sure NOT to use the IP address of the Docker network
>   adapter. It should be a number like 192.168.0.123.

Additionally, You can check [`lando info`](https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/external-access.html#checking-connection-info) to get info about the app.